# Do .NET Core console apps have a memory ceiling?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, miniprofiler

I have successfully deployed a series of solutions as .NET Core console apps. These run successfully under normal circumstances but often it appears the data load (using EntityFramework Core query with .ToList() to retain in memory for multiple accesses) seems to be blowing the process with no error but never at the same place. Does anyone know any established memory or process limits on .NET Core C# console apps to be aware of?  I never exceed the CPU or Memory on the hosting machine.  It tends to be that a list once accessed for the first time after .ToList() executed earlier in the code with a hefty query that fueled it will do an null object exception on the list.

This is .NET Core 2.0.0 SDK at this point.

If you know of published limits that would be excellent.  I am going to try using MiniProfiler to do forensics as well.  TIA.

Comment: Are you maybe running the app in 32 bit? then the 32 bit limits would apply..

Comment: Great question Martin.  Will check that out

Comment: Thanks @MartinUllrich.  Appreciate your asking the very basic question on this one.  I figured AnyCPU would suffice but probably needed to go to x64 directly for direct definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question was two-fold.  First...changing to x64 versus AnyCPU increased some ceiling but secondly the .Include() method in EntityFramework Core should be used sparingly and profiled.  This exploded the in-memory graph as well.  So yes a simple question which two people downgraded my question for may have been a simple answer yet it was exacerbated with .Include() that is a helper method yet can hurt you if not properly profiled and used.

Comment: This can also happen when the `IQueryable<>` interface is implicitly converted to `IEnumerable<>` and code is executed in .NET instead of making it part of the SQL query - this effectively could stream the entire database into memory instead of just loading query results.